# Modify OctoberCMS Laravel Plugin to Disable Form Username Change

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5, octobercms

I'm using [OctoberCMS](https://octobercms.com/) based on [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) with the official [Users](https://github.com/rainlab/user-plugin) plugin.

How can I modify this plugin to Disable or Deny Username Change?

The form can easily be hacked to allow change.

### Plugin

Here is the file on GitHub I need to edit: [Account.php](https://github.com/rainlab/user-plugin/blob/master/components/Account.php)

In the `onUpdate()` function, where it says `$user->fill`, it is saving all input fields.

I need to deny the `username` field in the function or with the validator.

```
public function onUpdate()
{
    if (!$user = $this->user()) {
        return;
    }

    $user->fill(post());
    $user->save();
```

### OctoberCMS

I set Login attribute to Username.

[image: Login Attribute]

### User Update Details

The User Update Page displays the form inputs a user can change:

**Full Name** is a column in the Database called `surname` that I don't use.
**Username** is the column `username`, the one I use, but it's not included on the default form.

[image: account update]

Though someone can add the `username` field in the browser just by inspect element, edit the HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="accountUsername">Username</label>
    <input name="username" type="text" id="accountUsername" value="Desired Username">
</div>
```

Submit and it will change the name and update the `username` column in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend the User model with something like this:

```
\RainLab\User\Models\User::extend(function($model) {

    $model->bindEvent('model.beforeUpdate', function() use ($model) {

        if ($model->isDirty('username')) {

            throw new \ValidationException(['username' => 'Sorry!...']);

        }

    });

});
```

The above code will have a global impact, if defined in a registration method, preventing the username from ever being changed. To restrict it only to the front-end, consider using an expression like `if (!App::runningInBackend()) { /* ... */ }`. Otherwise you could simply listen to the event on that page only, inside the `onInit` page code function.

Comment: Where should I place this code, at the top of the Account.php or the User.php model? I believe the Users plugin is limited to frontend only, so backend won't be affect.

Comment: I was able to get this to work and use it for more features, thanks.

Comment: @MattMcManis If you need global impact, define it in the `boot` method of one of your plugins, otherwise as Samuel said, put it in `onInit` method of your page.

Comment: @Meysam I have an addition to this question, would you be able to take a look at? http://stackoverflow.com/q/42721364/6806643