# OctoberCMS How to Override Users Plugin onRegister() Function?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, octobercms

I'm using [OctoberCMS](https://octobercms.com/) based on Laravel.

I'm trying to override the [Users Plugin](https://github.com/rainlab/user-plugin) `onRegister()` function.

[A previous answer helped me extend the plugin.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42690635/6806643)

I want to restrict Usernames to alphanumeric only with  `alpha_dash` and limit to 50 characters.

**The original function in [Account.php](https://github.com/rainlab/user-plugin/blob/master/components/Account.php)**

```
public function onRegister()
{
...
    if ($this->loginAttribute() == UserSettings::LOGIN_USERNAME) {
        $rules['username'] = 'required|between:2,255';
    }
```

**My Override**

Users Events docs https://github.com/rainlab/user-plugin#events

```
public function boot() {

    \RainLab\User\Models\User::extend(function($model) {

        $model->bindEvent('model.beforeUpdate', function() use ($model) {

            # User Register
            \Event::listen('rainlab.user.register', function($user, $data) {

                if ($this->loginAttribute() == UserSettings::LOGIN_USERNAME) {
                    $rules['username'] = 'required|alpha_dash|between:2,50';
                }

            });
        }); 
    }); 
}
```

**Error**

```
"Call to undefined method [loginAttribute]"
```

If I remove the if statement and loginAttribute and use only $rules['username'], I am still able to register names with non-alphanumeric characters.

I have been able to extend new code using this, but not override existing code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you understand the page cycle here.

`rainlab.user.register` is called **after** the user has already been registered. I.e. they have already passed validation and already exist with the invalid username.

What you can do instead is bind to the User model's `model.beforeSave` event and do your own validation of the username:

```
public function boot() {

    \RainLab\User\Models\User::extend(function($model) {

        $model->bindEvent('model.beforeSave', function() use ($model) {
            $validator = \Validator::make($model->attributes, [
                'username' => 'required|alpha_dash|between:2,50',
            ]);

            if ($validator->fails()) {
                throw new \ValidationException([
                    'username' => 'Username must contain alphanumeric values only, and be between 2 and 50 characters in length',
                ]);
            }
        });

    });

}
```

Comment: I have a new question maybe you can help me with https://stackoverflow.com/q/61545012/6806643