# OctoberCMS User Plugin How to Deny Reserved Names

Tags: octobercms

I'm using the [User plugin](https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-user).

Here is my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42721364/octobercms-how-to-override-users-plugin-onregister-function) on how to Deny Username Change.

I have a list of Reserved Names I don't want people to use (such as admin, anonymous, guest) I need to put in an array and deny upon register.

My Custom Component's Plugin.php

```
public function boot() {

    \RainLab\User\Models\User::extend(function($model) {

        $model->bindEvent('model.beforeSave', function() use ($model) {

            // Reserved Names List
            // Deny Registering if Name in List

        });

    });

}
```

How would I do that using the Validator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can throw an exception to do that

```
public function boot() {

\RainLab\User\Models\User::extend(function($model) {

    $model->bindEvent('model.beforeSave', function() use ($model) {

        $reserved = ['admin','anonymous','guest'];

        if(in_array($model->username,$reserved)){
            throw new \October\Rain\Exception\ValidationException(['username' => \Lang::get('You can't use a reserved word as username')]);
        }

    });

});
```

}

Comment: I believe it is working. This simplified the process.

Answer (score 5):

We can create validation rules using `Validator::extend():`

```
Validator::extend('not_contains', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    // Banned words
    $words = array('a***', 'f***', 's***');
    foreach ($words as $word)
    {
        if (stripos($value, $word) !== false) return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

The code above defines a validation rule called `not_contains` - it looks for presence of each word in `$words` in the fields value and returns false if any are found. Otherwise it returns true to indicate the validation passed.

We can then use our rule as normal:

```
$rules = array(
    'nickname' => 'required|not_contains',
);

$messages = array(
    'not_contains' => 'The :attribute must not contain banned words',
);

$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);

if ($validator->fails())
{
    return Redirect::to('register')->withErrors($validator);
}
```

Also check this out https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#custom-validation-rules to know how to deal with this in **OctoberCMS**.

Comment: I have the website in maintenance mode while in development, but I can view it while logged in the backend. When I extend the validator and put it in boot(), it locks me out of the backend and goes to the maintenance mode page.

Comment: I put it in the model about the rules. I get error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Validator' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)". How do I include the validator in the model? I tried 'use Validator' and 'use Illuminate\Validation\Validator'.

Comment: I put 'use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;' inside the class, outside the class, but I get same error "unexpected 'Validator'. I put it in boot() in the model I get error "Cannot make static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::boot() non static in class".

Comment: Thanks I found out just as you replied.