# OctoberCMS Builder MySQL Invalid default value for the integer column

Tags: mysql, database, octobercms

I built an [OctoberCMS](https://octobercms.com) site on a local VirtualBox LAMP server and moved it and the MySQL database to [A2 Shared Hosting](https://www.a2hosting.com).

---

#### Error

The live site is working fine, but when I use the [Builder](https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-builder) plugin to add a new database column and save, I get the error:

```
Invalid default value for the integer column 'sort_order'. The allowed formats are '10', '-10'.
```

But the value is `10`.

[image: database]

[image: error]

---

#### Servers

My **Local VirtualBox Server** is running `MySQL 5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`.

The **A2 Hosting Server** is running `MySQL 10.3.22-MariaDB-cll-lve`.

---

#### Database Connection

The `database.php` config file looks like this, with the database name, username, and password filled in.

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'     => 'mysql',
    'engine'     => 'InnoDB',
    'host'       => 'localhost',
    'port'       => 3306,
    'database'   => '',
    'username'   => '',
    'password'   => '',
    'charset'    => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation'  => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'     => '',
    'varcharmax' => 191,
],
```

---

#### Question

Why does saving the new column not work?
Does it have something to do with MySQL on the local server and MariaDB on the A2 server?

Comment: What happens if you change the engine to `MariaDB`??

Comment: @PettisBrandon It does not seem to have an effect. I have solved part of the problem. MariaDB will not accept `null` for `Integer`. But when I remove that, it will attempt to save, but fail at Timestamps. https://i.imgur.com/jAv7n04.png

Comment: @PettisBrandon If I delete the columns and save, then try to re-add them, it gives the error `SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'created_at' (SQL: alter table `mydatabasename_` add `created_at` timestamp null)`, even though the columns don't exist and are not duplicates.

Comment: What was your migration flow? Zipup, upload, unpackage? Or did you install OctoberCMS on A2 Hosting then migrate data?

Comment: @PettisBrandon On my Local VirtualBox server, I used phpMyAdmin to export the database as a `.sql` file. Then in A2 Hosting I used their phpMyAdmin to import the file. I copied the OctoberCMS site files through ftp and setup the `database.php` and other config files.

Comment: Try installing a clean version of OctoberCMS on the A2 hosting site in a subdomain or some subfolder. Then the builder plugin and see how it handles the database.